# Intersection between polygon and 3D coordinates data.frame

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, polygon, intersection

I need to intersect a coordinates system (x, y, z) with a polygon (x, y) and then understand which point intersect with also the z coordinate.

```
coo=matrix(1:15, 3,3);
colnames(coo)=c("x", "y", "z")
coo=as.data.frame(coo)
coordinates(coo)=~x+y+z
l3=readWKT("POLYGON((1.5 0,10 0,10 10,1.5 10, 1.5 0))")
```

I try with gIntersection of Package 'rgeos' and this is the results

```
a=gIntersection(coo, l3)
a
SpatialPoints:
  x y
1 2 5
1 3 6
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

Moreover I try with the option `byid=T` edn the function return which elements intersect but without z coordinate.
How I can do?

Comment: I'm not familiar w/ `WKT` - does the `POLYGON` you created have any z-coords?  Does it make a difference if you build it as `POLYGON((x y 0,x y 0,...` ?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Browsing around -- it's not clear to me that `sp` and `rgeos` support polygons in 3D.  Can someone else clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is:

1. Convert your object of class `spatial` into a data.frame.
2. Perform a `merge` between the two data.frames.
3. Convert the merged data.frame back to an object of class `spatial`.

There will be the intersected coordinates x, y and z.

```
coo=matrix(1:15, 3,3)
colnames(coo)=c("x", "y", "z")
coo=as.data.frame(coo)

require(sp)
coordinates(coo)=~x+y+z
l3=readWKT("POLYGON((1.5 0,10 0,10 10,1.5 10, 1.5 0))")

require(rgeos)
clip=gIntersection(coo,l3)
clip = data.frame(clip)

df = merge(clip,coo)
coordinates(df)=~x+y+z
```

The output is:

```
df 

SpatialPoints:
     x y z
[1,] 2 5 8
[2,] 3 6 9
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```